# Which clustering approach represents my time-series data

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, clustering

I have **time-series** data of 12 consumers. The data corresponding to 12 consumers (named as `a ... l`) is
[image]

I want to cluster these consumers so that I may know which of the consumers have utmost similar consumption behavior. Accordingly, I found clustering method [pamk](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fpc/docs/pamk), which automatically calculates the number of clusters in input data.

I assume that I have only two options to calculate the distance between any two time-series, i.e., [Euclidean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), and [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping). I tried both of them and I do get different clusters. Now the question is which one should I rely upon? and why?

When I use `Eulidean` distance I got following clusters:
[image]

and using `DTW` distance I got
[image]

**Conclusion:**
  How will you decide which clustering approach is the best in this case?

Comment: Why would DTW has anything to do with your data? Do you believe that actually what you are seeing is "common pattern" and actually your variation is due to horizontal/registration shifts? If anything the time-series you show do not have a clear landmark so DTW is not immediately obvious.

Comment: I build clusters using distance matrix, and the distances can be computed using either Euclidean or DTW. My concern is which one represents the data more accurately.

Comment: Duplicate cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686664/cluster-your-time-series-data/33692578 - please **don't cross-post but choose the one, more appropriate site**.

Comment: Assuming you only have "2" options would be a mistake. There is also *permutation distribution clustering* which has some well developed R modules for implementation here ... https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdc/index.html  Since your clusters are exploratory, you don't have a "ground truth" or benchmark against which to base a comparison. Try reversing this relationship and build models that classify the resulting clusters. Which approach minimizes the misclassification error?

Comment: What is the objective of your segmentation? IS the absolute time of day important in classifying similar customers or is it the temporal pattern observed independent of time? For example: a and d can be said to be similar because they had activities that spanned three hours long, as opposed to the fact that they were active at the same point in time. So to get more meaningful results it will be necessary for you to describe in more detail what you intend to achieve from the groups after clustering.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-posting my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686664/cluster-your-time-series-data/33692578#33692578

1. none of the timeseries above look similar to me. Do you *see* any pattern? Maybe there is no pattern?
2. the clustering visualizations indicate that **there are no clusters**, too. `b` and `l` appear to be the most unusual outliers; followed by `d,e,h`; but there are no clusters there.
3. Also try hierarchical clustering. The **dendrogram** may be more understandable.

But in either way, **there may be no clusters**. You need to be prepared for this outcome, and consider it a valid hypothesis. **Double-check any result**. As you have seen, pam will *always* return a result, and you have absolutely no means to decide which result is more "correct" than the other (most likely, **neither is correct**, and you should *rely* on neither, to answer your question).